# Average sentence length for every text in corpus (python3 & nltk)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, average, iterable

I'm analyzing the inaugural address corpus in the NLTK package as part of an introduction to python programming course. I'd like to find out the average sentence length of each text within the corpus (so that I can later compare them), but I seem to be stuck here.

I've created this function:

```
def averageSentence(text):
    sents = inaugural.sents(fileids=['fileid_here.txt']  
    avg = sum(len(word) for word in sents) / len(sents)  
    print(avg)
```

which (if I'm correct) should give me the average sentence length for an individual text. Now, I know I need a *for loop*. Shouldn't I be able to make a relatively easy and straightforward for loop with this function I just defined? This is very frustrating.

EDIT: this is how far I have gotten:

```
for fileid in inaugural.fileids():
    avg_sents = averageSentence(fileid)
    print = sum(avg_sents) / avg_sents
```

Comment: Please specify what problem you have exactly. What have you tried so far? What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: I apologize. I've now edited my OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> from nltk.corpus import inaugural
>>> total_lens = 0
>>> for i, sent in enumerate(inaugural.sents()):
...     total_lens += len(sent)
... 
>>> total_lens 
145735
>>> i
4867
>>> avg_sent_len = total_lens / i
>>> avg_sent_len
29.943497020752
>>> avg_sent_len = total_lens / (i+1)
>>> avg_sent_len
29.9373459326212
```

Note that when denominator large enough +1 doesn't really matter much.

---

**Mirco-averaged sentence length across all texts**

The following code is a one-liner but it's not encouraged, since you may have materialized a generator twice:

```
>>> sum(len(sent) for sent in inaugural.sents()) / len(inaugural.sents())
29.9373459326212
```

---

**Marco-averaged sentence length across all texts**:

```
>>> sum(sum(len(sent) for sent in inaugural.sents(fileids=[fileid])) / len(inaugural.sents(fileids=[fileid])) for fileid in inaugural.fileids()) / len(inaugural.fileids())
32.84054349411484
```

---

**Averge sentence length per text**:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> from nltk.corpus import inaugural
>>> inaugural.fileids()
[u'1789-Washington.txt', u'1793-Washington.txt', u'1797-Adams.txt', u'1801-Jefferson.txt', u'1805-Jefferson.txt', u'1809-Madison.txt', u'1813-Madison.txt', u'1817-Monroe.txt', u'1821-Monroe.txt', u'1825-Adams.txt', u'1829-Jackson.txt', u'1833-Jackson.txt', u'1837-VanBuren.txt', u'1841-Harrison.txt', u'1845-Polk.txt', u'1849-Taylor.txt', u'1853-Pierce.txt', u'1857-Buchanan.txt', u'1861-Lincoln.txt', u'1865-Lincoln.txt', u'1869-Grant.txt', u'1873-Grant.txt', u'1877-Hayes.txt', u'1881-Garfield.txt', u'1885-Cleveland.txt', u'1889-Harrison.txt', u'1893-Cleveland.txt', u'1897-McKinley.txt', u'1901-McKinley.txt', u'1905-Roosevelt.txt', u'1909-Taft.txt', u'1913-Wilson.txt', u'1917-Wilson.txt', u'1921-Harding.txt', u'1925-Coolidge.txt', u'1929-Hoover.txt', u'1933-Roosevelt.txt', u'1937-Roosevelt.txt', u'1941-Roosevelt.txt', u'1945-Roosevelt.txt', u'1949-Truman.txt', u'1953-Eisenhower.txt', u'1957-Eisenhower.txt', u'1961-Kennedy.txt', u'1965-Johnson.txt', u'1969-Nixon.txt', u'1973-Nixon.txt', u'1977-Carter.txt', u'1981-Reagan.txt', u'1985-Reagan.txt', u'1989-Bush.txt', u'1993-Clinton.txt', u'1997-Clinton.txt', u'2001-Bush.txt', u'2005-Bush.txt', u'2009-Obama.txt']
>>> for fileid in inaugural.fileids():
...     avg = sum(len(sent) for sent in inaugural.sents(fileids=[fileid])) / len(inaugural.sents(fileids=[fileid]))
...     print fileid, avg
... 
1789-Washington.txt 64.0833333333
1793-Washington.txt 36.75
1797-Adams.txt 69.8648648649
1801-Jefferson.txt 46.0714285714
1805-Jefferson.txt 52.9777777778
1809-Madison.txt 60.2380952381
1813-Madison.txt 39.5151515152
1817-Monroe.txt 30.2704918033
1821-Monroe.txt 38.0542635659
1825-Adams.txt 42.5675675676
1829-Jackson.txt 48.32
1833-Jackson.txt 42.2333333333
1837-VanBuren.txt 43.9052631579
1841-Harrison.txt 43.6428571429
1845-Polk.txt 33.9607843137
1849-Taylor.txt 53.7272727273
1853-Pierce.txt 35.1634615385
1857-Buchanan.txt 34.808988764
1861-Lincoln.txt 29.0217391304
1865-Lincoln.txt 29.0740740741
1869-Grant.txt 30.2195121951
1873-Grant.txt 33.5909090909
1877-Hayes.txt 46.1694915254
1881-Garfield.txt 28.9196428571
1885-Cleveland.txt 41.5454545455
1889-Harrison.txt 30.2547770701
1893-Cleveland.txt 37.1206896552
1897-McKinley.txt 33.6230769231
1901-McKinley.txt 24.5
1905-Roosevelt.txt 33.0606060606
1909-Taft.txt 36.7672955975
1913-Wilson.txt 28.0147058824
1917-Wilson.txt 27.6
1921-Harding.txt 25.2080536913
1925-Coolidge.txt 22.5482233503
1929-Hoover.txt 24.6202531646
1933-Roosevelt.txt 24.2705882353
1937-Roosevelt.txt 21.03125
1941-Roosevelt.txt 22.5882352941
1945-Roosevelt.txt 24.5
1949-Truman.txt 21.7931034483
1953-Eisenhower.txt 22.5609756098
1957-Eisenhower.txt 20.8369565217
1961-Kennedy.txt 29.7307692308
1965-Johnson.txt 18.2446808511
1969-Nixon.txt 22.8773584906
1973-Nixon.txt 29.3913043478
1977-Carter.txt 26.0377358491
1981-Reagan.txt 22.0551181102
1985-Reagan.txt 23.380952381
1989-Bush.txt 18.7103448276
1993-Clinton.txt 22.9012345679
1997-Clinton.txt 21.9821428571
2001-Bush.txt 18.8144329897
2005-Bush.txt 25.0105263158
2009-Obama.txt 24.3392857143
```

---

**Macro-averaged Word length averaged across all texts**:

```
>>> sum([sum(len(sent) for sent in inaugural.sents(fileids=[fileid])) for fileid in inaugural.fileids()]) / len(inaugural.fileids())
2602.410714285714
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but this essentially gives me the same solutions as what I already have. I'm not looking for an average of all the sentences in the corpus, but instead for each individual text in the corpus so that I'm able to compare the averages.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want "average text length per text" or "average sent length per text"?

Comment: Average sentence length per text as stated in my OP. Thank you, though, as you have helped me with your edited answer!

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped.